# Is the lack of tail call optimization an obstacle when using the Eventually workflow?

Tags: f#, tail-recursion, tail-call-optimization

I'm using a modified version of the Eventually workflow from the F# spec for my development on Xbox. The .net framework on the Xbox does not support tail calls, it seems. Because of this, I have to disable tail call optimization when compiling.

Although it might seem at first that this restriction would prevent the use of any form of looping in computation expressions, I initially thought that "stepping" would avoid that problem: A recursive function f in the computation expression does not call itself directly, instead it returns an Eventually value containing a lambda which calls f.

Experiments indicate that I was right about while loops (they don't cause stack overflows when used in computation expressions), but not about recursive functions.

To clarify, this works:

```
// Wait until "start" or "A" is pressed on one of the gamepads.
// Set "player" when that happens.
let player : PlayerIndex option ref = ref None
while (!player).IsNone do
    for p in all_players do
        let state = GamePad.GetState(p)
        if state.IsConnected
            && (state.Buttons.Start = ButtonState.Pressed
                || state.Buttons.A = ButtonState.Pressed) then
            player := Some p
    do! sys.WaitNextFrame()
```

This causes a stack overflow:

```
// Wait until "start" is pressed on the controlling gamepad.
let rec wait() = task {
    input.Update()
    if not (input.IsStartPressed()) then
        do! sys.WaitNextFrame()
        do! wait()
}
```

In the second case, the stack trace shows a long sequence of calls to "bind@17-1", whose code is shown below. The line number appearing in the stack trace is line 17.

```
let rec bind k e =
    match e with
    | Completed r ->
        Running(fun () -> k r)
    | Running f ->
        Running(fun () -> f() |> bind k)  // line 17
    | Blocked(dt, f) ->
        Blocked(dt, fun () -> f() |> bind k)
    | BlockedNextFrame f ->
        BlockedNextFrame(fun () -> f() |> bind k)
    | Yield f ->
        Yield(fun () -> f() |> bind k)
```

Where am I wrong? Is my reasoning about "steppable recursion" being harmless w.r.t. stack overflows incorrect? Is there something wrong with my implementation of bind?

Oh my head! Continuation-passing with recursion gives me headaches...

EDIT: "steppable recursion being harmless w.r.t. stack overflows" has got a name, I have just learned. It's called a trampoline.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

replace the last **do!** with **return!**:

```
// Wait until "start" is pressed on the controlling gamepad.
let rec wait() = task {
    input.Update()
    if not (input.IsStartPressed()) then
       do! sys.WaitNextFrame()
       return! wait()
}
```

**EDIT**

according to F# spec, **do! wait()** will be transformed to Bind(wait(), fun() -> Zero()), so every recursive call will increase level of Bind nesting (as you see in stacktrace)

in opposite **return! wait()** will immediately return new 'Eventually' computation that can be consumed on the next step.

Comment: Thanks, that's working! Now if only I understood why... Has it something to do with the fact that the `do! wait()` in my code was implicitly followed by `return()`?

Answer (score 6):

One way to understand what's happening is to look at the type signatures.

```
type TaskBuilder() =
    // do!
    // Eventually<'a> * ('a -> Eventually<'b>) -> Eventually<'b>
    member x.Bind(e, f) = bind f e

    // return!
    // Eventually<'a> -> Eventually<'a>
    member x.ReturnFrom(r : Eventually<_>) = r

    // return
    // 'a -> Eventually<'a>
    member x.Return(r) = result r


let result r = Completed(r)
```

All functions in f# have to return something. So the following code

```
let rec wait() = task {
    input.Update()
    if not (input.IsStartPressed()) then
        do! sys.WaitNextFrame()
        do! wait()
}
```

is equivalent to

```
let rec wait() = task {
    input.Update()
    if not (input.IsStartPressed()) then
        do! sys.WaitNextFrame()
        do! wait()
        return ()
}
```

If we look at the definition of Return it calls result which in-turn returns a Completed(r).

I made two small test for task.

```
let test7() =
    let sch = new Scheduler()
    let sys = new Environment(sch)

    let rec hop i = task {
        printfn "%i: Hop!" i
        //do! sys.Wait(1.0f)
        if i > 0 then
            do! hop (i - 1)
            return ()
    }

    runAllFixed sch 0.1f [| hop 3 |]

let test8() =
    let sch = new Scheduler()
    let sys = new Environment(sch)

    let rec hop i = task {
        printfn "%i: Hop!" i
        //do! sys.Wait(1.0f)
        if i > 0 then
            return! hop (i - 1)
    }

    runAllFixed sch 0.1f [| hop 3 |]

test7()
printfn "\n" 
test8()
```

With some instrumentation it prints.

```
Delay 3: Hop!
Delay Bind Running 2: Hop!
Delay Bind Running Running 1: Hop!
Delay Bind Running Running Running 0: Hop!
Zero Completed Running Running Return Completed Running Return Completed Return


Delay 3: Hop!
Delay ReturnFrom 2: Hop!
Delay ReturnFrom 1: Hop!
Delay ReturnFrom 0: Hop!
Zero
```

MSDN doc on [Computation Expression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233182.aspx) calls.

Comment: Both you and desco mention the result of do! being bound to `Zero()`, but as far as I have seen, this is not correct. Instead, it's bound to `Return()`. See http://cs.hubfs.net/forums/thread/18215.aspx . I don't know if that's a bug or a feature.

Comment: Your right.  The Zero is only executed at the end.  I'll update my answer in a little while.